# How to submit payment gateway radio button choosen in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have developed custom payment gateway and tried to choose another payment gateway and submit place order button. But my custom payment gateway is working after choosing another payment gateway also. I have ifram form submit through javascript event. How to proceed with this and solve this. Please guide me

```
//My custom payment gateway

         jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout button").on('click', function (e) {   
           if(jQuery('form').find('li').hasClass('payment_method_customgateway')){  
           //do the custom gaeway submission
            jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").trigger('submit');
            }else{
            jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").trigger('submit');
            }
         }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I suggest you take the [tour], it always can be useful. I think we don't have enough informations to answer you properly: how is the class `payment_method_customgateway` added to the form? How do you choose your different gateways (is it an admin setting or a user selection)? Also having the html code could probably help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout button").on('click', function (e) {
                         var payment_method = jQuery('form.checkout').find('input[name^="payment_method"]:checked').val();
if(payment_method=='custom_gateway'){
//do the submission
} else{
jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").trigger('submit');  
}
```

Comment: Glad you found an answer to your problem, however, the goal of SO is not only to help one specific person asking a question, but also to provide a set of useful Q/A for other people. As it it, with no explanation and very few details in the question, this is very unlikely that this answer would help someone else. It could be a good aide if you provide an answer to add some extra informations. Have a nice day!